# How to populate a part of a handsontable depending on user input

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, handsontable

I have a handsontable which loads after the user requests a new file creation.
The handsontable has 2 editable headers which are bar_code, and quantity, and the other columns are the details of each items and they are not editable by the user.
I want to make an ajax request that would read the barcodes entered by the user in the handsontable and fetches the corresponding item details from the database and then populates the rest of the handsontable with the corresponding item details for each barcode.
This function will be performed when the user hits the button save and this button will also convert the complete data in the table and save it to a JSON file.

I am completely new to ajax and I have tried to become familiar with the concept by reading w3schools tutorials ..etc but I can't seem to get a grasp of the concept.

Could anyone please advice?

Comment: Have you tried googling your request? I'm sure there is a tutorial for something like that already

Comment: Yes I have searched a lot but I can't seem to find anything.